# Assigning password to users created from CSV

Tags: bash, passwords, user-accounts

The script functions without error, but the password does not work on the accounts. Not sure why the password is not being assigned, any help would be awesome.

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=","

while read firstname lastname userid 
do 
    sudo useradd -c "'${firstname} ${lastname}'" -d /home/"${userid}"  -s /bin/bash "${userid}"  
    sudo usermod -p changeme123 "${userid}"  
    sudo usermod -G student "${userid}"

done < students.csv
```

Comment: What is happening? Are you getting an error? Are the users not being created? The `usermod` is not going to work because you are giving it the comment and not the login name. Also you don't need to quote the comment twice unless you want quotes *in* the comment string itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following line instead of usermod -p.

```
echo "${userid}:changeme123" | chpasswd
```

Need to look for piping sudo. Could not test it at the moment. Should be `sudo bash -c`.